# Bitbucket private repo npm throws a new error

Tags: node.js, git, docker, npm, bitbucket

Something was changed lately from npm and npm install started giving us this error:

```
npm ERR! Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

Then I found that the my private repo from package.json was causing this. I have a private repository in bitbucket and I have added in package.json like this

```
"pe-shared": "git+https://mike-be:hash@bitbucket.org/payfac0/pe-shared.git#1.4",
```

Any idea what has changed?

Comment: is the repo still up and running and that `1.4` tag, is it still present?

Comment: ofcourse. nothing was changed. I think something was changed from the npm server.